# Visual studio 2003 javascript comments

Tags: javascript, visual-studio

When editing javascript, if I need to comment out a large section of code I use  `/* Comment */`. This seems to work fine.

However if I then need to comment out a section of code which contains the first comment, I get problems.

e.g.

```
/*
/* 
alert('First bit of code');
*/
alert('Second bit of code');
*/
```

This gives a syntax error. It appears the first close tag closes both comments.

In later versions of visual studio, you have the option to comment out large sections of code by highlighting it and pressing the comment button. However it doesn't have this ability in 2003.

This is very inconvenient when editing large files. Is there a better method for me to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't nest comment blocks, not in javascript, not in C, Java or C#.

The moment you add a `/*` before a comment block, the `/*` that starts the original comment block is considered to be *commented out*, so the end of the original comment block closes the new `/*`.

Comment: Ok thanks. I'm looking for an alternative method though. I guess none exists.

Answer (score 0):

It's right: the second open comment tag is itself a comment, so it does not work.